# The three gates of hell: Lust, anger and greed. What are they? & Why are they bad?

Tags: krishna, gods, gita

In Gita god has told us about the gates of hell. Lust, anger and greed. What are each one of them? Why are they bad?

Answer (score 1):

Lust and greed are simply desire for worldly things. Gita itself answers the question why lust, greed and anger are bad.

> In one who dwells longingly on sense objects, an inclination towards
>   them is generated. This inclination develops into desire, and desire
>   begets anger.

*Gita 2.62*

> Anger generates delusion, and delusion results in loss of memory. Loss
>   of memory brings about discriminative intelligence, and loss of
>   discriminative intelligence spells ruin to a man.

*Gita 2.63*

> A man of disciplined mind, who has his senses under control and who
>   has neither attraction nor aversion for sense objects, attains
>   tranquillity, though he may be moving amidst objects of the senses.

*Gita 2.64*

> On attaining tranquillity all one's sorrows come to an end. For soon
>   does the intellect of a tranquil person becomes steady.

*Gita 2.65*